# Cookie Audit help needed

Tags: cookie

Can anyone recommend any decent cookie audit plugins for firefox or chrome

I can see the typical google cookies on the site but I am struggling to find out what a couple of the other cookies actually do

What is the best way to find out what a cookie actually does?

Comment: What a cookie does can only be worked out by looking at the code that uses it. Some of this is only on the server so can't be worked out by viewing the source of a webpage. You'll have to ask the people who wrote the code that created the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's ever worked for me, even then usually resulting in limited information, is to just search for the cookies' names. If it's anything interesting, there's generally a discussion someplace where people have already picked it apart as much as possible([ex. 1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/what-does-the-quantcast-qca-cookie-do), [ex. 2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25181/what-is-the-switchto5x-cookie-unam-qca)). But the reality is that in many cases, the companies responsible may not particularly *want* you to know what they do, so the names will be arcane, sometimes change, and the actual data in the cookies encoded.

Answer (score -1):

lots of cookies come from advertising and tracking websites, Collusion shows who's tracking you online

1. [firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=Collusion&appver=&platform=)
2. [chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Collusion?hl=en-US)

reference: http://www.pcworld.com/article/250986/firefox_addon_collusion_shows_whos_tracking_you_online.html

Comment: Collusion shows *who* is tracking you, but as far as I'm aware doesn't tell you which cookies are actually involved or what they do. If you know different, please update with a reference link.